# What is a good FFMPEG/AVISynth to upscale gaming videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, davinci-resolve, recommendation, avisynth, video-game

I plan to use Retroarch to dump and create videos from the various cores that are featured there. I had asked for advice from other places online ranging from recommended emulators to what video editing programs to use for editing. Although I thank them for giving me some good advice, there are still things that I still need some help on.

I want to ask what is a good setup for lossless, high quality videos that I can create on Retroarch? What is a good way to upscale my videos to 720p using FFMPEG/AVISynth? Retroarch usually dumps .mkv files so I figured that it would make my experience easier.

Comment: FFmpeg Nvidia/cuda scaler : `-vf scale_npp=w=1920:h=1080`

Comment: I also I am looking for the PointResixe/Nearest Neighbor equivalent in FFMPEG? I want it to 720p but I also want it to be as close to the original as possible.